# Redirecting Windows Events (WM_) to a hidden window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, hook

I'm currently working on a project that involves a significant amount of hooking and is designed to operate as an overlay for an interactive product in the same way the '[Steam Overlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_%28software%29#Steam_Overlay)' does.

The hooking part is actually complete. We have an 'invisible' WPF application that performs DLL injection, hooks DirectX, renders itself to a texture and then renders that texture on the application being hooked.

[image: Program structure]

The difficulty we're having is the latter part; getting input information intended for the overlay. As you can see in the diagram, the trivial example is a button being pushed. What I would like to do, is actually capture *all* input messages (WM_x) to the DirectX application and then let the WPF application decide which messages are relevant to the overlay and which aren't.

I have managed to hook the `WNDPROC` of the DirectX application by using...

```
IntPtr _oldWindProc = GetWindowLong(MainWindowHandle, Win32Helper.GWL_WNDPROC);
WndProcDelegate _myProc = new Win32Helper.WndProc(WndProc);
SetWindowLong(MainWindowHandle, Win32Helper.GWL_WNDPROC, _myProc );
```

...and this seems to work well. At this point I can pass all WM_x messages back to the WPF application. But that's where I am stuck. I have tried `PostMessage` and Spy++ shows the WPF window receiving the messages (and in fact setting a hook inside the WPF window reveals the same) but this doesn't seem to work as intended. So, what am I missing? Are there certain Windows messages I should be responding to? I naively assumed it'd be as simple as having the WPF application receive a "WM_LBUTTONDOWN" at the correct location and the button would depress.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I might have glossed over the actual problem a bit. I want to redirect the messages to the WPF as if that was their intended destination. I have already hooked the messages and blocked them from going to the DirectX application. The question is how I can pass them on to the WPF application seamlessly.

Comment: This cannot work, the messages have the wrong window handle.

Comment: I don't think that's true. I already have the message id and both param variables so I can pass it on with the handle of the WPF window, no problem. But where do I pass it and how?

Comment: The function you are looking for is `CallWindowProc()`, but it is probably better to use the hook solution provided by Motes below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were too many edge reasons why this wouldn't work as intended so I resorted to manually patching the specific events that I wanted (mouse events, basically).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dll with `SetWindowsHookEx` to hook the directx app and pass it's messages back to subclassed window on your main app. I have done this in C++, you should be able to do it in C# using pinvoke or something. Here is the code in C++:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int _stdcall InstallHook(DWORD dwThreadId, HWND ExtrnHandle, HWND Apphandle)
{
    if (hHook==0)
            hWndApp = Apphandle;
            hWndHooked = ExtrnHandle;
            hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE,(HOOKPROC) GetMsgProc, (HINSTANCE) hInstance, dwThreadId);
        if (hHook==0) return GetLastError();
    return 0;
}
```

Use this to unhook:

```
 __declspec(dllexport) int UnInstallHook(void)
{
    LRESULT result;
    if (hHook != 0){
        result = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
        if (result == 0) return GetLastError();
        hHook = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then use this call back in you dll to pass the message back to the app:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MSG *lpMsg;

    if (nCode==HC_ACTION){
        lpMsg = (MSG *) lParam;
        //see if this is the window we are monitoring
        if (lpMsg->hwnd == hWndHooked){
            //forward the message to App
            ChangeMessage=false;
            SendMessage(hWndApp, lpMsg->message, lpMsg->wParam, lpMsg->lParam);
            if (ChangeMessage==true){//Did App make changes to the data?
                lpMsg->message = Shared_uMsg;
                lpMsg->wParam = Shared_wParam;
                lpMsg->lParam = Shared_lParam;

            }//end if change message

        }//end if correct hWnd
    }//end if nCode==Action     
    return(CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Also, fyi, here is the code at the top of the dll .cpp file, declartions, a function to set shared data, etc:

```
#include "afxdisp.h" //this does #include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include "WINUSER.H"    
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define WM_MOUSEWHEEL 0x020A 
#define COPY2CLIPBOARD 1 //for copying data from msflexgrid
#define COPY2FILE      2

/*---------------------------------------------
          Shared Variables
This data is shared between both prcesses.  The
VB App has access to these variables through the
function SetSharedData
---------------------------------------------*/
#pragma data_seg(".shared")
    bool ChangeMessage = false;
    int Shared_uMsg = 0;
    int Shared_wParam = 0;
    int Shared_lParam = 0;
    int CopyMode = COPY2FILE;
    HWND hWndApp = 0; //handle to subclassed Window
    HWND hWndHooked = 0;//handle to the hooked window
    HHOOK   hHook = 0;      // Hook handle for WH_GETMESSAGE

#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.shared,RWS")

//---------------------------------------------
// Global Variables, specific to each process
//---------------------------------------------
    HINSTANCE   hInstance;  // Global instance handle for DLL



//--------------------------------------------
//        DLL entry-point
//--------------------------------------------
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  // handle to DLL module
    DWORD fdwReason,     // reason for calling function
    LPVOID lpvReserved )  // reserved
{
    // Perform actions based on the reason for calling.
    switch( fdwReason ) 
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         // Initialize once for each new process.
         // Return FALSE to fail DLL load.
            hInstance = hinstDLL;//save dll handle for each process
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
         // Do thread-specific initialization.
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
         // Do thread-specific cleanup.
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
         // Perform any necessary cleanup.
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;  // Successful DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.
}

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

__declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall SetSharedData(int uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        Shared_uMsg = uMsg;
        Shared_wParam = wParam;
        Shared_lParam = lParam;
        ChangeMessage = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this will work. It looks like it is just calling SendMessage to push the message toward the window handle, whereas my solution uses PostMessage. Although I'm not sure what HC_ACTION does...

Comment: HC_ACTION specifies that you can process the message, otherwise the callback should immediately return callnexthookex. This is different than what you did, though, I don't understand what your doing perhaps if you provide more code with your example. What I did was set  a system wide hook and filter for the messages we want. The only reason I used sendmessage is to check if the external app wanted to change the message.

Comment: If your external app is recieving messages, it must process them to dispatch to it's children which must in turn process their messages.Most the time wndprocs are done in the background automatically, though you can create them manually and not rely on the default wndproc. But, it seems your subclassing my have messed up the default message processing on you window, as you seem to be changing the address of the wndproc to intercept messages instead of using `SetWindowsHookEx`. You can also use `SetWindowsHookEx` with a `CallWndProc` callback instead of `GetMsgProc`.

Comment: Rodrigo pointed out as well that `CallWindowProc(__in  WNDPROC lpPrevWndFunc,
  __in  HWND hWnd,
  __in  UINT Msg,
  __in  WPARAM wParam,
  __in  LPARAM lParam)` 
should be used with your technique.

lpPrevWndFunc-The previous window procedure. If this value is obtained by calling the GetWindowLong function with the nIndex parameter set to GWL_WNDPROC or DWL_DLGPROC, it is actually either the address of a window or dialog box procedure, or a special internal value meaningful only to CallWindowProc

Comment: We're addressing the wrong problem here. Apologies if my question is unclear; I don't have a problem hooking the messages intended for the DirectX application. I have those messages and I can pass them back to my WPF application as data. The problem is, once I have the message data, how do I apply that message to my WPF window. If I have intercepted a WM_LBUTTONDOWN at {X=100, Y=200}, how do I make that call on the WPF window, as if the message was intended for it. Calling PostMessage/SendMessage doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly how you are hooking and passing the messages.